# Calculo de una celda dependiendo del resultado de otras celdas

Tags: excel, condiciones, porcentaje

me está siendo imposible conseguir hacer funcionar una fórmula en excel, a ver si me podéis echar un cable, os pongo en materia.

Tengo esta tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que en la celda E2 me aparezca la comisión que se lleva ese comercial, dependiendo del valor de la fila C y D, es decir:

Si el comercial 1 hace una produción de 5000€ y la celda C2 contiene un dato y la celda D2 contiene NO, la comisión de B2 sería de un 30%

Si el comercial 1 hace una produción de 5000€ y la celda C2 está vacia y la celda D2 contiene SI, la comisión de B2 sería de un 20%

Si el comercial 1 hace una produción de 5000€ y la celda C2 NO contiene un dato (está en blanco) y la celda D2 contiene NO, la comisión de B2 sería de un 40%

No soy capaz de dar con la tecla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `SI` anidada, combinada con la función `AND` para obtener el resultado que esperas.

```
=IF(AND(B2=5000,C2<>"",D2="NO"),B2*30%,(IF(AND(B2=5000,C2="",D2="SI"),B2*20%,IF(AND(B2=5000,C2="",D2="NO"),B2*40%,0))))
```

En la función más interna pasas el valor cero si no se cumple la condición y esta última función pasaría a ser el parámetro si no se cumple la condición anterior.

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una forma de representar estas anidaciones de forma "mas gráfica" u orienta a programación, sería la siguiente:

```
if (B2=5000 && C2<>"" && D2="NO") {
    B2*30%
} else {
    if (B2=5000 && C2="" && D2="SI") {
        B2*20%
    } else {
        if (B2=5000 && C2="" && D2="NO") {
            B2*40%
        } else {
            0
        }
    }
}
```

Como observación, debes sustituir las **,** (coma) por **;** (punto y coma) en caso de que la configuración local de tu equipo sea diferente.

Comment: Agradecido @DjCrazy , me estaba volviendo loco

Comment: Para eso está la comunidad :), no para volverse loco jaja, sino mas bien para compartir el conocimiento. Como recomendación, en tus próximas preguntas agrega el código que has probado, qué no funciona o detalles adicionales que puedan complementar la pregunta y faciliten la respuesta. [Haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que comprendas el motivo de esta observación. Ah y dale click al botón upvote, así ambos ganamos reputación en la comunidad. Éxitos!